# Modifying artifact version in a Maven Mojo

Tags: java, maven, versioning, lifecycle, mojo

Just starting to get into Maven and building custom Mojos. Hoping someone can help here.

The general idea is that I want to modify the version in the POM without modifying the POM itself. I'm going to use this functionality to add qualifiers to the end of the version that gets deployed. For example, I might change `1.0` to `1.0-SNAPSHOT`, `1.0-RELEASE`, `1.0.123` (based on the most recent incremental version), or `1.0-a1b2c3d` (based on a Git commit hash). The goal here is that the developer doesn't have to worry about changing the version number (when it doesn't matter), but rather the build handles that.

So I'm trying to update the version number as part of the `initialize` phase, but it's not sticking in all the places I'm expecting. Here's my Mojo:

```
package com.tomkel.maven;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;

/**
 * This goal overrides the current artifact version
 *
 * @goal overrideVersion
 *
 * @phase initialize
 */
public class VersionOverrideGoal
    extends AbstractMojo
{
    /**
     * @parameter default-value="${project}"
     */
    private MavenProject mavenProject;

    /**
     * Run the Mojo
     * @throws org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException
     */
    public void execute()
        throws MojoExecutionException
    {
        this.mavenProject.setVersion("TRY_THIS");
        this.mavenProject.getArtifact().setVersion("TRY_THIS_TOO");
    }

}
```

But when I include this in my project's POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.tomkel</groupId>
    <artifactId>tk-version-override-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>overrideVersion</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then I see something like this during the `install` phase of the project build:

```
[INFO] Building jar: /home/tkelley/git/tomkel/some-project/target/some-project-1.2.3.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3:install (default-install) @ some-project ---
[INFO] Installing /home/tkelley/git/tomkel/some-project/target/some-project-1.2.3.jar to /home/tkelley/.m2/repository/com/tomkel/some-project/TRY_THIS_TOO/some-project-TRY_THIS_TOO.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/tkelley/git/tomkel/some-project/pom.xml to /home/tkelley/.m2/repository/com/tomkel/some-project/TRY_THIS_TOO/some-project-TRY_THIS_TOO.pom
```

Because the artifact is built as `some-project-1.2.3.jar`, my repository (nexus) is adding this as version `1.2.3`. But that's not what I want -- I'd like it be added as `TRY_THIS_TOO`.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

If it helps, I've put the Mojo code, the POMs, and build logs into a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/tomkel5/8199801

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @jtahlborn The primary reason is this: Our build system builds both commits and [uncommitted] Pull Requests from Github. When it's building an actual commit, I want it to build and deploy the normal version, but when it's building a Pull Request, I want to build and deploy a snapshot.

Comment: Any luck? I need this too.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use the [Versions Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) to manage your versioning.

Comment: I tried using the `set` and `revert` goals, but I need to `revert` *after* the `deploy` phase. `deploy` is the final phase, so I'm not sure how to execute something after it.

Comment: @ThomasKelley why can't you trigger the `revert` goal during the `deploy` phase? Maven can't affect the contents inside the packaged artifact after the `package` phase so it leaves the POM inside the package with the SNAPSHOT version but still reverts the source POM. In other words, the process of uploading the packaged artifact somewhere (`deploy`) and reverting the source POM are independent of each other and thus can execute in parallel.